# Cannot change font-family for class

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have the following html

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Hello</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Herr+Von+Muellerhoff' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">



</head>

<body>
<h1 class = "hidden">Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css linked is as follows

```
body{
    font-size: small;

}
h1.hidden
{
    font-family: 'Herr Von Muellerhoff', cursive;
}
```

when `.hidden` is appended to `h1`, the font does not change, but without the `.hidden` the font will change to the google loaded font, why is this? Not sure if this code matters, but this is the javascript linked to the html file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('h1.hidden').fadeIn(5000).removeClass('hidden');
});

});
```

Comment: With `.hidden` or without `.hidden` works?! http://jsbin.com/kahayimejo/1/ what's you mean?

Answer (score 5):

Your code removes the class `hidden` *immediately*, not after the fade completes. So what happens is most likely that you don't get the chance to see the CSS in action.

To remove the class after the fade completes, use

```
$('h1.hidden').fadeIn(5000, function() { $(this).removeClass('hidden') });
```

And finally, you really don't need to nest a `$(document).ready` inside of another.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add !important with font-family in .hidden class.

```
h1.hidden
{
    font-family: 'Herr Von Muellerhoff', cursive !important;
}
```